# Html.Raw splits string unintentionally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on a page, where customers can write own descriptions for articles they sell. They can use html tags for this.

The code in the view looks like this:

```
@Html.Raw("<p class='description short'>" + shopItem.ShortDescription + "</p>")
```

The problem is, that this is splitted into two p-tags:

```
<p class="description short"></p>
```

and below that the content of shopItem.ShortDescription:

```
<p><em><strong>Title</strong></em></p>
```

I also tried

```
<p class="description short">@Html.Raw(shopItem.ShortDescription)</p>
```

but that leads to the same behavior.

I´m sure I´m missing or not seeing something. So, what is wrong with that code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue here is that you cannot nest p elements. If you try it with just html it still will not work, but for example this works fine

```
@{     
    var shopItem = "<em><strong>Title</strong></em>";
}
@Html.Raw("<p class='description short'>" + shopItem + "</p>")
```